# How to send a post request with HttpClient

Tags: java, eclipse, httpclient

Does anyone know how I would go about updating a page using a post request in Java Eclipse with the HttpClient library? Currently this is what I have, but when 
I execute it I get a page not found error:

```
public void update() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://examplepage.xml");
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_action", "<BasicPage><title>New Title</title></BasicPage>"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_method", "post"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String info = (""+EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        System.out.println(info);
        System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContent());
        System.out.println(response);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Check that the page URI or alias "examplepage.xml" actually exists or mapped. Check also that it can accept POST requests.

Comment: ahh sorry i meant that there's another real url in there, like neopets.com/neopet.xml. like that format, and its a locked page and ive already used another post request to get in there.